# Replaying packets on local machine other than loopback

Tags: network-interface, tcpreplay

This might sound very wierd; but can I replay a pcap file on a interface other than lo in local machine? I want to get packets on lets say eth1. It is not attached to any link as of now. I want the packets to come in and not go out of eth1. I do not have physical access to machine; so I cannot go and plug-in a wire to eth1 from some other machine and use it for playing.

Comment: Have you tried manually assigning an IP address to eth1 and then sending the packets to that address?

Comment: yeah I did assign IP to that interface; but still used -i eth1 switch in tcpreplay. Let me check if we can pass IP to it.

Comment: I am not sure how to replay it on specific IP. I cannot see a switch for it; I can see one for rewriting dest ip in packets though